# React-native release build error on iOS: ld: library not found for -lReact

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am doing a Release scheme react-native build in Xcode and I get the following error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-qwfopvasfnhysedskapbaefsdwer/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/React' ld: library not found for -lReact clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to add libReact.a in Link Binary With Libraries section in Build Phases but I can't find the library in my workspace.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try `react-native link` in your terminal? there may be a chance that you forgot to link a library.

Comment: Hi @Harrison! react-native link doesn't work because the project uses custom paths since react-native was integrated into existing native android/ios projects. I have to manually link libraries, but I get the "ld: library not found for -lReact" error.